# SUMIFS function having a sum range as a product of 2 ranges, Array Formulas

Tags: arrays, excel, product, formulas, sumifs

I'm trying to minimize creating uneccessary tables in Excel, and instead of creating a table to multiply columns `A` and `B`, can I do it within the `IF` formula? Perhaps using Array formulas?

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the following formula:

```
SUMIFS($A$1:$A$10*$B$1:$B$10,$C$1:$C$10,"Value")
```

however it did not work.

Basically, I want to sum the product of `A` & `B` (i.e `A*B`) if the value in `C` is equal to `"value"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SumProduct` is what you need

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$B$10,--($C$1:$C$10="Value"))
```

Entered as a standard (not array) formula

Comment: this worked, thanks
I havent seen the double dash -- in a formula before, what does it do generally?

Comment: It's double negative. It's purpose is to type cast a Boolean to a number

Answer (score 0):

This formula checks if the value in Column C is equal to 4 in this example. If so, it returns the product, if not, it returns 0. You enter this formula in for example column D and drag it down.

```
=IF(C1=4;SUMPRODUCT(A1:B1);0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for one row at a time, i want to also sum the values of multiple rows.